# Adjunctions restrict to an equivalence

Tags: category-theory, adjoint-functors

From [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3164620/prove-that-adjunction-restricts-to-an-equivalence-between-full-subcategories):

> Let a pair of functors $F : \mathscr{A} \rightarrow \mathscr{B}$ and $G : \mathscr{B} \rightarrow \mathscr{A}$ be adjunction such that $F$ is left adjoint to $G$, i.e. $F \dashv G $. Write $\textbf{Fix}(GF)$ for the full subcategory of $\mathscr{A}$ whose objects are those $A \in \mathscr{A}$ such that $\eta_{A}$ is an isomorphism, and dually $\textbf{Fix}(FG) \subseteq \mathscr{B}$. Prove that the adjunction $(F, G, \eta, \epsilon)$ restricts to an equivalence $(F', G', \eta', \epsilon')$ between $\textbf{Fix}(GF)$ and $\textbf{Fix}(FG)$.

So we need to prove that the functor $F':\textbf{Fix}(FG)\to \textbf{Fix}(FG)$ defined by $F'(A)=F(A),\ F'(f)=F(f)$ is full, faithful, and essentially surjective on objects.

Essential surjectivity on objects seems to be obvious: if $B\in \textbf{Fix}(FG)$, then since $\epsilon_B:FG(B)\to B$ is an isomorphism, $B$ is isomorphic to $F(A)$ where $A=G(B)$.

But fullness and faithfulness is not as obvious to me.

*Fullness*: Suppose there is an arrow $F(A)\to F(A')$ for some $A,A'\in \mathscr A$. We need to prove that this arrow is the image (under $F$) of some arrow $A\to A'$ in $\mathscr A$. Since $F\dashv G$, there is a bijection $$\mathscr B (F(A),F(A'))\cong\mathscr A(A,GF(A'))$$
such that some naturality conditions hold. (And $GF(A')$ is isomorphic to $A'$ via $\eta_A$.) But the bijective correspondence from right to left is not necessarily given by $F(-)$. I don't have other ideas how to find the preimage of $F(A)\to F(A')$.

*Faithfulness*: Suppose there are two arrows $f,g:A\to A'$ such that $F(f)=F(g):F(A)\to F(A')$. We need to show that $f=g$. I can't think of any applicable technique of proving that two arrows are equal. Nor do I understand how to use that $F(f)=F(g)$.

Comment: Have you tried using that, in this case, also $GF(f)=GF(g)$?

Comment: You don't need to do this! You can just explicitly exhibit the inverse of $F'$!

Comment: @QiaochuYuan An obvious guess would be that the inverse of $F'$ is $G'$ (which is $G$ restricted to $\textbf{Fix}(FG)$). But then one has to prove that the two compositions are naturally isomorphic to the identities. Is it really easier than proving that $F'$ is full and faithful?

Comment: Probably it is, because the components of $\eta$ and $\epsilon$ would be isomorphisms in this case... I'll try to post an answer.

Comment: @KevinCarlson I've posted a different proof, but I still don't see how to use $GF(f)=GF(g)$ to implement the original idea of the proof.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $$F': \mathbf{Fix}(GF)\to \mathbf{Fix}(FG)$$ be the functor defined by $F'(A)=F(A)$ and $F'(f)=F(f)$ for all objects $A$ and arrows $f$ in $\mathbf{Fix}(GF)$. (See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3384625/showing-that-functors-restrict-properly) for a proof of the fact that $F'(A)\in\mathbf{Fix}(FG)$ and that $F'(f)$ is a morphism in $\mathbf{Fix}(FG)$.) Similarly, let $$G':\mathbf{Fix}(FG)\to\mathbf{Fix}(GF)$$ be the functor defined by $G'(B)=G(B)$ and $G'(g)=G(g)$ for all objects $B$ and arrows $g$ in $\mathbf{Fix}(FG)$.

Let $\eta':1_{\mathbf{Fix}(GF)}\to G'\circ F'$ be the natural transformation whose component at $A\in \mathbf{Fix}(GF)$ is given by $\eta'_A=\eta_A$. This is indeed a natural transformation because $\eta$ is. And let $\epsilon':F'\circ G'\to 1_{\mathbf{Fix}(FG)}$ be the natural transformation whose component at $B\in \mathbf{Fix}(FG)$ is $\epsilon_B'=\epsilon_B$.

Now it is almost immediate that $(F',G',\eta',\epsilon')$ is an equivalence. To establish this, we need to prove that $\eta'$ and $\epsilon'$ are natural isomorphisms, but they indeed are because their components are isomorphisms. (If $A\in \mathbf{Fix}(GF)$, then by the definition of $\mathbf{Fix}(GF)$, $\eta_A:A\to GF(A)$ is an isomorphism, hence so is $\eta'_A:A\to GF(A)$; and similarly for $\epsilon$.)

Comment: One thing I'm confused about is that I don't see how the fact that $\mathbf{Fix}(GF)$ is a *full* subcategory is used.

Comment: I think you need to use that they are full subcategories to show that the codomains of your functors $F'$ and $G'$ restrict properly.

Comment: @MattFeller What exactly do you mean by this? Do you mean it's used in proving that $F'(A)$ is actually an object of $\mathbf{Fix}(FG)$ (not just $\mathscr B$)? I didn't think about this when writing the proof, it's not very obvious to me now.

Comment: You do need to show that the functors restrict on objects, but what I was talking about is that you also need to check that the functors restrict properly in morphisms as well.

Comment: Some details about restrictions: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3384625/showing-that-functors-restrict-properly