# Showing that functors restrict properly

Tags: proof-verification, category-theory, adjoint-functors

This question is about a problem from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3359118/adjunctions-restrict-to-an-equivalence). I'll restate it:

> Let a pair of functors $F : \mathscr{A} \rightarrow \mathscr{B}$ and $G : \mathscr{B} \rightarrow \mathscr{A}$ be adjunction such that $F$ is left adjoint to $G$, i.e. $F \dashv G $. Write $\textbf{Fix}(GF)$ for the full subcategory of $\mathscr{A}$ whose objects are those $A \in \mathscr{A}$ such that $\eta_{A}$ is an isomorphism, and dually $\textbf{Fix}(FG) \subseteq \mathscr{B}$. Prove that the adjunction $(F, G, \eta, \epsilon)$ restricts to an equivalence $(F', G', \eta', \epsilon')$ between $\textbf{Fix}(GF)$ and $\textbf{Fix}(FG)$.

I posted an answer in the link above, but it's incomplete. Namely, it doesn't prove that $F'(A)\in \mathbf{Fix}(FG)$, that $F'(a\to a')\in \mathbf{Fix}(FG)(F'(a),F'(a'))$ for any arrow $(a\to a')\in \mathbf{Fix}(GF)(a,a')$, and similarly for $G'$.

Here is my attempt to prove the above facts.

---

**(1)** Let $A\in \mathbf {Fix}(GF)$. We show that $F'(A)\in \textbf{Fix}(FG)$. The assumption means that $\eta_A:A\to GF(A)$ is an isomorphism. And we need to prove that $\epsilon_{F(A)}: FGF(A)\to F(A)$ is an isomorphism. Since $F\dashv G$, the following diagrams commute (Leinster, Lemma 2.2.2):

[image]

Look at the left diagram. Since $\eta_A$ is an isomorphism, then so is $F(\eta_A)$ since functors preserve isomorphisms. The arrow $1_{F(A)}$ is an isomorphism too. So the vertical arrow $\epsilon_{F(A)}$ must be an isomorphism too, q.e.d.

Is this argument correct?

---

**(2)** Suppose $a\to a'$ is an arrow in $\mathbf{Fix}(GF)$. We need to show that its image under $F'$ is in $\mathbf{Fix}(FG)$. But since $\mathbf{Fix}(GF)$ is full, the set of arrows in $\mathscr A$ is equal to the set of arrows in $\mathbf{Fix}(GF)$. So $F'(a\to a')=F(a\to a')\in \mathscr B(F(a),F(a'))$. But $\mathscr B(F(a),F(a'))$ is equal to $\mathbf{Fix}(FG)(F(a),F(a'))$ since $\mathbf{Fix}(FG)$ is full.

Is this argument correct?

---

**(3)** Finally, we need to prove the analogous statements for $G'$.  I can do a proof similar to **(1)**, but can I somehow appeal to duality without doing the proof again? How exactly?

Comment: Yes, all correct. For (3), I guess you can simply take the opposite categories.

Comment: @Berci Thank you. Regarding (3), everybody just says that to prove the dual statement one "takes the opposite categories", but my question was what exactly do do with them after "taking" them.